# Equality of two elliptics integrals

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

I'm looking for a way to prove the equality of the following two integrals with $a > b > 0$. Thanks.

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\left(t^2+\frac{(a+b)^2}{4} \right) \left(t^2+\frac{(a-b)^2}{4} \right)}} dt = 2 \int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(t^2+a^2)(t^2+a^2-b^2)}} dt$$

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @tired is there a substitution to do ?

Comment: This is the [*Landen transformation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landen%27s_transformation) in disguise. Let $A = a+b$ and $B = a-b$ to check that your identity is essentially equivalent to $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2 + A^2)(x^2 + B^2)}} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2 + (\frac{A+B}{2})^2)(x^2 + AB)}}. $$

Comment: @SangchulLee Tanks a lot, that was the trick !